# Error message when trying to install GTFSR library

Tags: r, install.packages, gtfs

At the company I work for we are trying to advance our GTFS capabilities and I can across the GTFSR library, which got me very excited!

Being quite new to R it took me awhile to figure out I needed to install devtools, unfortunately, even after installing devtools, I get the following error:

```
devtools::install_github('ropenscilabs/gtfsr')
```

> Downloading GitHub repo ropenscilabs/gtfsr@master
>
> from URL
>   https://api.github.com/repos/ropenscilabs/gtfsr/zipball/master
>   Installing gtfsr Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/leaflet@master from
>   URL https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/leaflet/zipball/master
>   Installing leaflet "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file
>   --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \   "C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMr0ZUc/devtools2b9c242555c/rstudio-leaflet-6aa608f"
>   --library="C:/Program  \   Files/R/R-3.4.4/library" --install-tests
>
> In R CMD INSTALL Installation failed: Command failed (65535)
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ
>   --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \   "C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMr0ZUc/devtools2b9c2a431852/ropensci-gtfsr-3af920a"
>   --library="C:/Program  \   Files/R/R-3.4.4/library" --install-tests
>
> In R CMD INSTALL Installation failed: Command failed (65535)
>
> library(gtfsr)
>   Error in library(gtfsr) : there is no package called ‘gtfsr’

Comment: I think the username should be "ropensci" - `devtools::install_github(ropensci/gtfsr)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did determine what the issue was but I ended up uninstalling RStudio (and all packages) and reinstalled. I installed GTFSR by itself and it worked fine.

I wonder if maybe I had a conflicting package or an unsupported version.

Thanks everyone.